# Command line tool for Google drive like Dropbox Uploader

Tags: google-drive-api, dropbox, command-line-interface

Is there any open source project for Google Drive API via command line interface.

I'm detected a CLI project for Dropbox.
https://github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader

Also My product required GDrive CLI access program.

Is there any project ? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [GoogleCL](https://code.google.com/p/googlecl/). They have an interface for Docs, but in reality it supports arbitrary file types and stores the results in your Drive.

Beware though, you do need a specific of python-gdata (part of the package). Make sure to get the latest version of the code and you should be good. See [here](https://code.google.com/p/googlecl/wiki/UploadingGoogleDocs) for more details.

Comment: There is also [this](https://github.com/tom-dignan/gdrive-cli) which uses the actual Drive API, but apparently you have to publish an app to the chrome store first.. Odd if you ask me, but presumably it will work.  

Google also has a bunch of other file system tools listed [here](https://code.google.com/p/gdrive-linux/wiki/Tools)